# Python 3 - Search List or Dictionary

Tags: python

I am writing a program to retrieve json data, in which the data values are fixed.

The values returned will be either

```
'UN','VP','PO','MO','GO','VG','EX'
```

When the program runs, the expected return will be something like the following:

```
outlook1 = 'UN'
outlook2 = 'VP'
outlook3 = 'PO'
outlook4 = 'MO'
outlook5 = 'GO'
outlook6 = 'VG'
outlook7 = 'EX'
```

I want the program to read the two letter value assigned and change it to a more descriptive output.

```
a = ['UN','VP','PO','MO','GO','VG','EX']
b = ['Unknown', 'Very Poor', 'Poor', 'Moderate', 'Good', 'Very Good', 
'Excellent']
```

so 'VP' will become 'Very Poor'

I thought of using a dictionary also but cannot think of how to match keys and values to data that has been set.

```
dict1 = {'UN':'Unknown','VP':'Very Poor','PO':'Poor','MO':'Moderate',
        'GO':'Good','VG':'Very Good','EX':'Excellent'}
```

the only way I have been able to solve this so far is with a very long if-elif statement

```
x = []

if outlook1 == 'UN':
    x.append(b[0])
elif outlook1 == 'VP':
    x.append(b[1])
elif outlook1 == 'PO':
    x.append(b[2])
elif outlook1 == 'MO':
    x.append(b[3])
elif outlook1 == 'GO':
    x.append(b[4])
elif outlook1 == 'VG':
    x.append(b[5])
elif outlook1 == 'EX':
    x.append(b[6])
```

Here is my code:

```
import requests
import urllib.parse
import texttable as tt

main_api = 'example.org'
key='123456789'

url = main_api + urllib.parse.urlencode({'key':key})

json_data = requests.get(url).json()

block1_time = json_data["SiteRep"]["DV"]["Location"]["Period"][1]["Rep"][0]["$"]
block1_f = json_data["SiteRep"]["DV"]["Location"]["Period"][1]["Rep"][0]["F"]
block1_s = json_data["SiteRep"]["DV"]["Location"]["Period"][1]["Rep"][0]["S"]
block1_h = json_data["SiteRep"]["DV"]["Location"]["Period"][1]["Rep"][0]["H"]
block1_t = json_data["SiteRep"]["DV"]["Location"]["Period"][1]["Rep"][0]["T"]
block1_v = json_data["SiteRep"]["DV"]["Location"]["Period"][1]["Rep"][0]["V"]
block1_d = json_data["SiteRep"]["DV"]["Location"]["Period"][1]["Rep"][0]["D"]
block1_u = json_data["SiteRep"]["DV"]["Location"]["Period"][1]["Rep"][0]["U"]
block1_w = json_data["SiteRep"]["DV"]["Location"]["Period"][1]["Rep"][0]["W"]
block1_p = json_data["SiteRep"]["DV"]["Location"]["Period"][1]["Rep"][0]["Pp"]

dates = ['00:00','03:00','06:00','09:00','12:00','15:00','18:00','21:00']
temp = []
feels = []
speed = []
direc = []
humid = []
visib = []
wtype = []
prob = []
uvind = []

descr = ['Unknown', 'Very Poor', 'Poor', 'Moderate', 'Good', 'Very Good', 
    'Excellent'] #[0-6]
if block1_v == 'UN':
    visib.append(descr[0])
elif block1_v == 'VP':
    visib.append(descr[1])
elif block1_v == 'PO':
    visib.append(descr[2])
elif block1_v == 'MO':
    visib.append(descr[3])
elif block1_v == 'GO':
    visib.append(descr[4])
elif block1_v == 'VG':
    visib.append(descr[5])
elif block1_v == 'EX':
    visib.append(descr[6])
```

The empty lists are appended and used to populate a TextTable.

There must be an easier way in python. Hope this makes things clearer and any Help Much Appreciated.

****UPDATE****json data****

{"SiteRep":{"Wx":{"Param":[{"name":"F","units":"C","$":"Feels Like Temperature"},{"name":"G","units":"mph","$":"Wind Gust"},{"name":"H","units":"%","$":"Screen Relative Humidity"},{"name":"T","units":"C","$":"Temperature"},{"name":"V","units":"","$":"Visibility"},{"name":"D","units":"compass","$":"Wind Direction"},{"name":"S","units":"mph","$":"Wind Speed"},{"name":"U","units":"","$":"Max UV Index"},{"name":"W","units":"","$":"Weather Type"},{"name":"Pp","units":"%","$":"Precipitation Probability"}]},"DV":{"dataDate":"2017-11-12T18:00:00Z","type":"Forecast","Location":{"i":"26","lat":"53.3336","lon":"-2.85","name":"LIVERPOOL JOHN LENNON AIRPORT","country":"ENGLAND","continent":"EUROPE","elevation":"22.0","Period":[{"type":"Day","value":"2017-11-12Z","Rep":[{"D":"NNW","F":"4","G":"22","H":"57","Pp":"0","S":"18","T":"8","V":"VG","W":"1","U":"1","$":"900"},{"D":"NNW","F":"2","G":"29","H":"65","Pp":"0","S":"11","T":"6","V":"VG","W":"0","U":"0","$":"1080"},{"D":"NNW","F":"2","G":"27","H":"67","Pp":"0","S":"11","T":"5","V":"VG","W":"0","U":"0","$":"1260"}]},{"type":"Day","value":"2017-11-13Z","Rep":[{"D":"NNW","F":"1","G":"25","H":"71","Pp":"0","S":"11","T":"5","V":"VG","W":"0","U":"0","$":"0"},{"D":"NNW","F":"0","G":"22","H":"74","Pp":"0","S":"11","T":"4","V":"VG","W":"0","U":"0","$":"180"},{"D":"NNW","F":"0","G":"18","H":"77","Pp":"0","S":"9","T":"3","V":"VG","W":"0","U":"0","$":"360"},{"D":"W","F":"2","G":"9","H":"82","Pp":"1","S":"2","T":"4","V":"GO","W":"3","U":"1","$":"540"},{"D":"S","F":"5","G":"7","H":"74","Pp":"5","S":"4","T":"6","V":"GO","W":"7","U":"1","$":"720"},{"D":"SSW","F":"6","G":"11","H":"80","Pp":"5","S":"7","T":"7","V":"GO","W":"7","U":"1","$":"900"},{"D":"SSW","F":"5","G":"16","H":"79","Pp":"6","S":"7","T":"7","V":"GO","W":"7","U":"0","$":"1080"},{"D":"SSW","F":"5","G":"18","H":"79","Pp":"6","S":"9","T":"7","V":"VG","W":"7","U":"0","$":"1260"}]},{"type":"Day","value":"2017-11-14Z","Rep":[{"D":"SSW","F":"5","G":"18","H":"87","Pp":"50","S":"9","T":"8","V":"VG","W":"12","U":"0","$":"0"},{"D":"SW","F":"7","G":"20","H":"92","Pp":"52","S":"9","T":"9","V":"GO","W":"12","U":"0","$":"180"},{"D":"WSW","F":"8","G":"20","H":"91","Pp":"14","S":"11","T":"10","V":"VG","W":"7","U":"0","$":"360"},{"D":"WSW","F":"8","G":"20","H":"91","Pp":"17","S":"11","T":"10","V":"GO","W":"8","U":"1","$":"540"},{"D":"W","F":"10","G":"16","H":"92","Pp":"61","S":"9","T":"12","V":"MO","W":"12","U":"1","$":"720"},{"D":"SW","F":"11","G":"11","H":"92","Pp":"53","S":"7","T":"11","V":"GO","W":"12","U":"1","$":"900"},{"D":"S","F":"10","G":"9","H":"94","Pp":"15","S":"4","T":"10","V":"MO","W":"7","U":"0","$":"1080"},{"D":"WSW","F":"9","G":"13","H":"92","Pp":"15","S":"9","T":"10","V":"GO","W":"8","U":"0","$":"1260"}]},{"type":"Day","value":"2017-11-15Z","Rep":[{"D":"WSW","F":"9","G":"13","H":"93","Pp":"54","S":"7","T":"10","V":"GO","W":"12","U":"0","$":"0"},{"D":"WSW","F":"9","G":"11","H":"93","Pp":"14","S":"7","T":"10","V":"GO","W":"7","U":"0","$":"180"},{"D":"NW","F":"8","G":"11","H":"91","Pp":"11","S":"7","T":"9","V":"GO","W":"7","U":"0","$":"360"},{"D":"SE","F":"8","G":"11","H":"91","Pp":"7","S":"7","T":"10","V":"GO","W":"7","U":"1","$":"540"},{"D":"S","F":"10","G":"11","H":"87","Pp":"8","S":"7","T":"11","V":"GO","W":"7","U":"1","$":"720"},{"D":"SSE","F":"10","G":"13","H":"87","Pp":"15","S":"7","T":"11","V":"GO","W":"8","U":"1","$":"900"},{"D":"SSE","F":"8","G":"13","H":"92","Pp":"11","S":"7","T":"10","V":"GO","W":"7","U":"0","$":"1080"},{"D":"S","F":"8","G":"16","H":"92","Pp":"8","S":"9","T":"10","V":"GO","W":"7","U":"0","$":"1260"}]},{"type":"Day","value":"2017-11-16Z","Rep":[{"D":"S","F":"7","G":"16","H":"93","Pp":"7","S":"9","T":"9","V":"GO","W":"7","U":"0","$":"0"},{"D":"S","F":"7","G":"16","H":"93","Pp":"7","S":"9","T":"9","V":"GO","W":"7","U":"0","$":"180"},{"D":"S","F":"7","G":"18","H":"92","Pp":"7","S":"9","T":"9","V":"GO","W":"7","U":"0","$":"360"},{"D":"S","F":"7","G":"20","H":"90","Pp":"14","S":"11","T":"10","V":"GO","W":"7","U":"1","$":"540"},{"D":"SSW","F":"9","G":"25","H":"84","Pp":"9","S":"13","T":"11","V":"GO","W":"7","U":"1","$":"720"},{"D":"SW","F":"8","G":"27","H":"84","Pp":"55","S":"16","T":"11","V":"GO","W":"12","U":"1","$":"900"},{"D":"SW","F":"7","G":"25","H":"79","Pp":"14","S":"11","T":"10","V":"VG","W":"7","U":"0","$":"1080"},{"D":"W","F":"6","G":"25","H":"78","Pp":"14","S":"13","T":"9","V":"GO","W":"7","U":"0","$":"1260"}]}]}}}}

Comment: Hmmm... there are easier ways but I am having trouble understanding your expected output.

Comment: What do you mean "I thought of using a dictionary also but cannot think of how to match keys and values to data that has been set"? Have you read up on [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)?

Comment: sorry I haven't explained it very well. When I run the script it will return values for outlook1 - 6. So if for instance outlook1 value is 'VG', when I print outlook1 value it will say 'Very Good'. If you have an easier way would like to see it and yes I have read on dictionaries just looking for some idea's on how to improve. Thanks.

Comment: A dictionary is the right idea, I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: @zeeman how is the dict supposed to return outlook 1 -6? Show us more of your code. This is confusing.

Comment: I have added more of the code hope this helps.

Comment: Are you just looking for`visib.append(dict1[block1_v])`?

Comment: Im sorry I have doen this all wrong. I will re-write and ask the question again. Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = ['UN','VP','PO','MO','GO','VG','EX']
b = ['Unknown', 'Very Poor', 'Poor', 'Moderate', 'Good', 'Very Good', 
'Excellent']
```

Then say you have a variable `c` that contains a `2` character string from `a`, you can get its corresponding description from `b` with:

```
b[a.index(c)]
```

so with `c = "MO"`, the above gives `"Moderate"`. Hopefully you can incorporate this into your code to remove the chunky `if-statements`.

Answer (score 0):

It is as simple as this:

```
dict1 = {'UN':'Unknown','VP':'Very Poor','PO':'Poor','MO':'Moderate',
        'GO':'Good','VG':'Very Good','EX':'Excellent'}

block1_v = json_data["SiteRep"]["DV"]["Location"]["Period"][1]["Rep"][0]["V"]

visib.append(dict1[block1_v])
```

Comment: I get what your saying but it doesnt help. I just need a way to shorten the code down so I dont have so may if-statements.

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can try some regex here :

Its an example, you can modify the code and use the captured group as you want.

```
dict1 = {'UN':'Unknown','VP':'Very Poor','PO':'Poor','MO':'Moderate',
        'GO':'Good','VG':'Very Good','EX':'Excellent'}

a = ['UN','VP','PO','MO','GO','VG','EX']

import re
data="""outlook1 = 'UN'
outlook2 = 'VP'
outlook3 = 'PO'
outlook4 = 'MO'
outlook5 = 'GO'
outlook6 = 'VG'
outlook7 = 'EX'"""

final=[]
pattern="outlook\d\s[=]\s'(\w{0,2})'"
match=re.finditer(pattern,data)
for find in match:

    for key,value in enumerate(dict1.items()):
        if str(find.group(1))==str(value[0]):
            final.insert(a.index(value[0]),value[1])

print(final)
```

output:

```
['Unknown', 'Very Poor', 'Poor', 'Moderate', 'Good', 'Very Good', 'Excellent']
```

> or if you want `outlook` with value then you can try :

```
final={}
pattern="(outlook\d)\s[=]\s'(\w{0,2})'"
match=re.finditer(pattern,data)
for find in match:

    for key,value in enumerate(dict1.items()):
        if str(find.group(2))==str(value[0]):
            final[find.group(1)]=value[1]

print(final)
```

output:

```
{'outlook2': 'Very Poor', 'outlook5': 'Good', 'outlook6': 'Very Good', 'outlook3': 'Poor', 'outlook4': 'Moderate', 'outlook1': 'Unknown', 'outlook7': 'Excellent'}
```